# XML, Encoded , C# SOAP

Tags: c#, xml, soap, literals

I pass a data to soap webservices that contains '<' and '>' tags. But in XML files '<' and '>' convert to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.
I use UTF-8 encoding.
How can I solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: including '<' or '>' in xml data elements would result in an error, which is why these characters are encoded ([more info here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)). It is not clear what you're asking...

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Can you show us the code you are using to call the soap webservice in the form of a [mcve]?

Comment: I send data like <first>ok</first> but in xml it seems like  &lt;first&gt;ok&lt;/first&gt;

Comment: Please show the **source code** (that is trying to send that XML) in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: that is from source code

Comment: `that is from source code` I mean literally show us the source code. Something that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

XML escaping works like html escaping, so you can use the same symbol codes.
In your case you should replace '<' and '>' with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

Other escapes that might be useful are:

`&apos;` for `'`

`&quot;` for `"`

`&amp;` for `&`

Comment: I send data like <first>ok</first> but in xml it seems like &lt;first&gt;ok&lt;/first&gt;